# Como separo meus arrays por indice?

Tags: php, array, for

São geradas as caixas de texto correspondentes ao número que o usuário inseriu, cada caixa de texto vem acompanhada de vários checkbox pra escolher o tipo de texto.

Porém sai assim :

```
Array ( [0] => 0 ) object(ElementosDTO)#7 (2) { 

    ["texto":"ElementosDTO":private]=> array(2) { 
       [1]=> string(5) "fdsfs" 
       [2]=> string(4) "sfsd" 
    } 
    ["idTipoElemento":"ElementosDTO":private]=> array(2) { 
        [1]=> string(1) "3" 
        [2]=> string(1) "3" 
     } 
}
```

como faço pra juntar os índices? Por exemplo, cada texto com seu id tipo elemento ?

Comment: Como você está gerando essa saída?

Comment: eu usei o var_dump()

Comment: Não, o seu código.